# What are the effects of using object relational mapping on software performance?

Tags: performance, orm

what are the effects of using object relational mapping on software performance?
Does ORM increase performance or decrease it? 
and Does it differ in various software projects?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is a hard question, but generally automatically generated code (ORM-code) may be slower since ORM librares are "not so clever" as developers.

But in any way, properly used ORM with good caching is "fast enough" and you should not care of the performance. You should care of which instructions use and which avoid.
You should always check what SQL is generated by ORM engine and on "tuning" phase of your project you can rewrite this parts of code of which performance is not acceptable.

Example of performance-killing operation is eager loading of collection of certain object (with one to many relation).